# Channel creation failed. Problem with key group channel application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Couldn't create my channel and got following error:

```
2021-01-27 10:32:42.643 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

Any idea how to solve this error?
How can I change this key [Group] /Channel/Application version?

Comment: It seems you already have created a channel. Try `peer channel list`

Comment: When I try the command `peer channel list` I have following error: `Fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml` . How can I set this path correct?

Comment: are you running test-network?

Comment: yes...it's the basic of the project

Comment: are you running these commands manually or through script

Comment: I don't understand. I tried some stuff and now I have not this error anymore but different like `No such Container: cli` - I think something is really going wrong...

Comment: am running it manually in a terminal

Comment: but actually am let them run trough a script, so that I need to do only one command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are inside the `test-network` directory and run the following commands

```
source scriptUtils.sh
. scripts/envVar.sh
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
```

Now try to run the create channel command
Make sure you have `configtx.yaml` present inside config directory

Comment: Thanks! In the test network I could solve the error now. Unfortunaetly in my "project" which is based on the test network, it's not working now...maybe it's a problem with the VM... I will check...